# How to control events scheduling in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to manually schedule the events in AnyLogic? or does the order of creating the model plays a role in that?.

I am creating a complex system which currently not behaving in the same order I am expecting. I looked at AnyLogic help and Stuart Rossiter explanation but, I was not able to draw answers for these two questions.

My approach to the problem is to use FIFO in the experiment with a statechart that is knotted with guards for each state (true if related are all complete ). And I was thinking to use a manually programmed time parameter for the whole model to order the events exactly as I want. I am not sure that this is the right approach or if I will work. Please guide me on that matter.

Thanks InAdvance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my answers:

1. Yes, there is a way to control the events manually (synchronizing).
   Its done by creating several events and ordering their
   trigger/re-occurrence times similar to the simulated phenomena.
2. No, of you are using manual synchronizing, and I don't know about Asynchronous modeling

the approach mentioned in the question did not work :).